# Document sets and views

Tags: document-set

Can I have different columns visible on the intial view different than the view that is shown after I click on a document set?

i.e. I have a setup a document set to allow a particular content type.  That content type has a column 'Test'.  I want to show this column when within a document set however when listing all document sets i do not want to show the column 'Test'.  Can this be accomplished?

thx

Answer (score 1):

The listing of all document sets is just a view of the document library, just exclude the column Test from the view. 
When you select a document set a 'welcome page' is shown with details about the document set and the documents in the set. I guess what you want is to show the column Test on the welcome page, this can be accomplished in the settings of the document set content type.